# migrate space in Contentful between organizations?

Tags: content-management-system, contentful, contentful-management

How to migrate space in Contentful between organizations?
Is there any way to migrate project space with all contents, settings, and webhooks from on organization to another?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways:

1. Contact support and they can move your entire space. This means it will be gone from the original organization though.
2. If you still need the original space left intact you can use the import export tooling https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/import-and-export/ Basically you export your original space and then import it to your new organization.